# How to debug LLVM code using lldb?

Tags: llvm, lldb

I have a piece of hand-written llvm assembly that I want to debug with lldb.

How do I make llc emit debugging information so that lldb could display the original llvm assembly instead of the native at&t-style assembly it's displaying at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a pass called DebugIR that would add debug info to LLVM IR, however it was removed in r222945. My guess is that it wasn't maintained properly and was bit-rotting. You could try revive it though!